# Ubuntu will not boot. Only getting extremely fast scrolling text

Tags: boot

I am only getting a flickering screen of writing going too fast to read. But they start with a green [ OK] and sometimes [failed]. This is after choosing to install or try from usb. I have done the md5checksums

Worth noting this isn't exclusive to ubuntu. I have mint installed and cannot boot unless I go through recovery mode and boot without hardware video accelerating if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: Recovery mode uses the nomodeset boot parameter, which is often required until you install a proprietary video driver. Most often with nVidia. What vidia card/chip do you have? What brand/model system? http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Setting nomodeset let's me boot into ubuntu. So what do you think the issue is?

Comment: Your video driver.

Comment: Problem was fixed with this script: http://iam.tj/prototype/enhancements/Windows-acpi_osi.html

I don't understand exactly what it did, but it worked.

Comment: @neil, if the problem is fixed, feel free to add your own answer, don't put the solution in the question, otherwise your question will hold the unanswered state.

Comment: Ok sorry, fixed

Comment: I had the same problem with my laptop. Then I checked the AMD documentation for that card and got to know that only selected linux OS supports that card. In short they have stopped developing those particular drivers further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was fixed with this script: http://iam.tj/prototype/enhancements/Windows-acpi_osi.html

```
#!/bin/sh
VERSION="$(sudo strings /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/DSDT | grep -i 'windows ' | sort | tail -1)"
echo 'Linux kernel command-line options required: acpi_osi=! "acpi_osi='$VERSION'"'
read -p "Do you want to add this setting (y/n) ? " answer
if [ x$answer != xY -a x$answer != xy ]; then
  exit 1
fi
echo "Existing Command Line: ` sed -n '/.*linux[[:space:]].*root=\(.*\)/{s//BOOT_IMAGE=\1/ p;q;}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg `"
if grep -m 1 'acpi_osi=Windows' -q /etc/default/grub; then
  echo "There is already an entry; please remove it from /etc/default/grub and redo 'sudo update-grub' then re-run this script"
  exit 2
fi
sudo sed -i "s/^\(GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=.*\)\"$/\1 acpi_osi=! \\\\\"acpi_osi=$VERSION\\\\\"\"/" /etc/default/grub
echo "Modified Command Line: ` sed -n '/.*linux[[:space:]].*root=\(.*\)/{s//BOOT_IMAGE=\1/ p;q;}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg `"
sudo update-grub
```

I don't understand exactly what it did, but it worked.

Comment: Do not run scripts from random sites, unless you know exactly what it does. It could be dangerous. But, it added acpi_osi=$VERSION to grub. Not sure what $VERSION is on your system, but on mine it is a blank. I have seen some specific systems need `acpi_osi=linux` boot parameter. Better to just manually edit `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`