# Endless Boot with fast scrolling text showing [ ok ]

Tags: boot, system-installation, lubuntu, intel-graphics, bootloader

I wanted to have a look/go at Linux so when I saw an old netbook for £15 I thought I would give it a go on a test machine. Here are the [specs](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/Eee_PC_1015PX/specifications/) which show the [CPU is 64-bit](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/55637/intel-atom-processor-n570-1m-cache-1-66-ghz.html) and I have the [Intel GMA 3150 Graphics adapter](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Asus-Eee-PC-1015PX-Netbook.70557.0.html).

When I bought it, it had 32-bit Windows 7 working fine with <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> keys not working. I had an unused SSD so put that in and installed Lubuntu 64-bit off a live USB drive. It would not boot except in safe mode.

I then thought I would try a different distro, LXDE 32-bit (the laptop only has 1 GB RAM). Again I did this from a live USB and seem to go flawlessly.

However all I get on a normal book up is very fast scrolling text/checks with all of them stating `[ ok ]` with one starting `/dev/sda1…`.. I cant read the rest from this photo I took; the text [moves too fast to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W69GA.jpg).

Again I can boot in safe mode and get a terminal but as I am new to Linux I don’t know what to check.

From searching on forums, it sounds like a graphics problem. I have tried the solution on ‘[Ubuntu will not boot. Only getting extremely fast scrolling text](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019832/ubuntu-will-not-boot-only-getting-extremely-fast-scrolling-text)’ but no luck.

I am really keen of getting it up and running and if all goes well buying a better small laptop for full blown 64-bit Ubuntu. However I want to get over this hurdle first.

Comment: Your photo shows the usual boot text. There is nothing there that gives a clue as to what could be wrong. If you suspect a graphics issue, try to boot with `nomodeset`: see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu) on how to do that.

Comment: Is there a check going on or even an error with /dev/sda1?

Comment: I've got also an EeePc (but the 1001PXD) with Xubuntu 16.04, just be really patient because that low consumption computer is really SLOW, even with a really light desktop as XFCE (I compared LXDE and XFCE, and XFCE is just a little bit slower than LXDE on it). I just hope that you removed the Windows 7 OS on it, it didn't like at all the dual-boot (Windows was already too slow for mine, about 10 minutes to start)

Comment: Please be specific when you refer to OS/release. You primarily seem to refer to desktop (LXDE) and not specifics on OS & release. I tested Lubuntu up to and including 19.04 using a x86 1gb RAM laptop using laptops older than your eeepc; but I'd like specifics of what you tried, and did you verify download was perfect? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and write to install media was flawless? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck  *You may also want to check you downloaded from the official site as many sites offer Lubuntu on google*

Comment: Adding _nomodeset_ into the boot commands of GRUB https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/  is your next step. Go to https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/197910 and scroll down to the section "Black/purple screen after you boot Ubuntu for the first time" which shows how to add _nomodeset_ temporarily. If that fixes it, then add it permanently with https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38834#38834

Comment: Guiverc - apologies I meant LXLE, downloaded from their website. I will try the CD integrity check. Nomodeset did not work, will try again though. Something did happen when I was trying these things. I was late to hit shift to take me to the grub screen and the laptop already started to boot, I pressed shift (didnt hold it) anyway for some reason and it ran some checks and booted strait up. Why? This has confused me! When i don't press shift right at the start of the boot it just gets stuck as mentioned before. Any help or reasoning would be greatly appreciated.